# Proxy Design Pattern encapsulation solution?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-4.0, delegates, proxy-pattern

I want to  execute a function but before  that , I want to verify the password.

I choosed to use the Proxy Design Pattern.

---

in words :

create the Proxy class,

send the password ,

and tell him **WHAT FUNCTION TO EXECUTE** if password is ok.

the problem is that According to Proxy Pattern the whole internals should/better be private.

so - I cant see from outside the Method1/2...

and i dont want to make `Method1/2` `public` ( and I dont want If's) . I want to use delegates.

So , how ( from outside) can I send him a valid `Action` param ? ( the `ac` param)

Should I crate to each function a public Action ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the method that you want to execute should not be part of your proxy class. It's a method that the caller of this class is passing:

```
public class ProxyClass
{
    public ProxyClass(string password, Action ac)
    {
        if (password == "111")
        {
            ac();
        }
    }
}
```

and then you could pass an `Action` as second argument:

```
var proxy = new ProxyClass("111", () => 
{
    ... some code that you want to execute in case of success
});
```

or if you already have some method defined:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Success() 
    {
        ... some code that you want to execute in case of success
    }
}
```

you could:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var proxy = new ProxyClass("111", foo.Success);
```

of if Success was a static method you don't need an instance of `Foo`:

```
var proxy = new ProxyClass("111", Foo.Success);
```

Comment: So method1/2() should be visible to the CALLER of the Proxy ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, well, if you define them inside the proxy as you did, then yes, they should be visible so that the caller can decide which one to call. And if those methods are not part of your proxy class, then the caller could pass them from somewhere else. But of course, since it's the caller that needs to pass an Action as second argument to the constructor, this Action should be known to the caller.

Comment: Seems weird to me that a design pattern which its usages is access control - enforce me to put the methods as public / visible to everyone.....